# POST from react gets sent with an empty body to the express server, NetworkError

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, firefox

We have this project that consists of a react frontend and an express backend. I am mainly responsible for the backend, whily my colleague is responsible for the frontend. The react server is running on `http://localhost:3000` with a proxy to `https://localhost:443` which is, of course, the express server. When we send a fetch POST-request to the server, the request gets sent as an OPTIONS-request by the browser, and the server responds with an appropriate response. I think I understand this is because of different ports and the same-origin-policy.

Now I don't understand how to fix this to allow the communication while react is still a dev-server. I have tried setting the CORS headers by myself in the express app, and it being done by the cors npm-package.. But those didn't change anything, except for the response by the server. Also, I edited the firefox about:config settings for cors which didn't help, either. This way, the firefox console doesn't show a warning about CORS or a NetworkError.

When I remove the header from the fetch request, the server gets the request, but the firefox console [shows errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRva9.png) and the request body is empty. The error is about an [object not being extensible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_define_property_object_not_extensible?utm_source=mozilla&utm_medium=firefox-console-errors&utm_campaign=default), but I don't know which object, or why. I suspect it's the request's body.

How should I proceed to make the communication possible?

This is the fetch code (by my colleague):

```
handleFormSubmit(event) {
event.preventDefault();
fetch("https://localhost/api/signup", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    username: "thisName",
    email: "thismail@react.com",
    password: "password"
  })
})
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    if (res.status === 200) return res.json();
    else return { status: res.status };
  })
  .then(responseJson => {
    console.log(responseJson.test, responseJson.status);
  });
}
```

While this is the custom app header (which I got from another stackoverflow question, I work with typescript)

```
this.app.use(function(req: any, res: any, next: any) {      
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "http://localhost/api/signup"
  );

  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "X-Requested-With,content-type"
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  next();
});
```

Comment: Where are you running your express API? Are you running this locally on port 80?

Comment: The server is running locally on port 443 with a redirect route from 80 to 443.

Comment: In your fetch you are using `https`, try `http` instead.